# Are advertising / crowd-sourcing questions acceptable or not?

Tags: discussion

Some of you will probably know about [tlcontrib](http://tlcontrib.metatex.org) already. I would like to ask for new volunteer members to register and upload extra packages, but I am not sure whether something like that is appropriate, as it is a question without any real answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, those types of solicitations, as well-intentioned as they are, would be considered spam.

If you think it through a bit, you begin to see the problem: Everyone thinks their services are useful and of interest to this community. They may be but, if you use *that* as the criteria, this site would quickly fill up with advertisements, solicitations, and spam. So we really cannot allow that type of activity on these sites.

Comment: Is there a chance of having free ads along the lines of what Taco proposes, analogous to the free software ads carried by the SOFU sites?

Comment: There are no ads running on these sites and they're not likely to install the ad modules to host free ads. The ad server is a fairly resource-intensive operation. We can take a look at various *giving back* programs if we start running ads.